# Prevent known_hosts Authenticity Check

Tags: php, ssh, phpseclib

I'm using phpseclib to connect to a server which has just been created. It will never have been connected to won't appear in `~/.ssh/known_hosts`. To prevent a script timeout from happening I'd like to bypass the warning:

```
The authenticity of host 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is xxx.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?
```

I know that a flag can be passed to OpenSSH to disable this authenticity check:

```
ssh -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no user@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

Is this a feature that has made its way into phpseclib?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

phpseclib doesn't - nor can it - verify a hosts authenticity.

What phpseclib does is it lets you retrieve the server public host key via `$ssh->getServerPublicHostKey()`. You can do so before you log into the server and you can save the key somewhere, be it in the DB or on the filesystem, and check against that saved key on future connections.

I mean, where would phpseclib save the server public host key anyway? It doesn't know if you have DB access. It doesn't know if any of the filesystem is writable. I suppose it could make use of tempnam() but then, like you said, what does it do on initial connections? Assume you're running it via a web browser (and not the CLI) and present a js popup? And tempnam() isn't permanent anyway. Is it supposed to re-prompt you every time /tmp gets deleted by the filesystem?

Comment: I understand that it doesn't try to verify a hosts authenticity, but how come my CLI script is showing the verify authenticity warning?

Comment: Scratch that, something else was invoking the check!

Comment: This must have changed because my current issue is that Net_SSH2() from phpseclib will not connect to a new device unless I first connect manually and say "yes" when it asks me to verify the validity of the new fingerprint.

Comment: @DustinSoodak - phpseclib has no way of knowing whether or not OpenSSH has made a successful connection via the CLI. For that matter you don't even need OpenSSH installed on a system for phpseclib to work...